# Is there any way to display float bar in chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to display float bar on a browser.
But the item of float bar can not be found.
Is there no way to display it in Chart.js?

This page I found on GitHub was modifying Chart.js.

https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/5262

http://pravopys.net/chartjs/samples/charts/bar/horizontal.html

However, I did not understand how to modify it.

Also, this page seemed to be trying to implement float bar support. However, it does not seem to be implemented yet.

https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/6056

I will put the code of the page of float bar introduced above.
However, even if this code was used, only the lower part was displayed.
I think that it is also necessary to modify Chart.js itself.

```
window.chartColors = {
    red: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
    orange: 'rgb(255, 159, 64)',
    yellow: 'rgb(255, 205, 86)',
    green: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
    blue: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
    purple: 'rgb(153, 102, 255)',
    grey: 'rgb(201, 203, 207)'
};
window.randomScalingFactor = function() {
    // return Math.round(Samples.utils.rand(-100, 100));
    return (Math.random()*200 - 100);
};
if (document.location.hostname.match(/^(www\.)?chartjs\.org$/)) {
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
    ga('create', 'UA-28909194-3', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
}
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
var MONTHS = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
var color = Chart.helpers.color;
var horizontalBarChartData = {
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Dataset 1',
        backgroundColor: color(window.chartColors.red).alpha(0.5).rgbString(),
        borderColor: window.chartColors.red,
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: [
            [20, 70],
            [-20,-70],
            [getRandomInt(10,50), getRandomInt(50,100)],
            [getRandomInt(10,50), getRandomInt(50,100)],
            [getRandomInt(10,50), getRandomInt(50,100)],
            [getRandomInt(10,50), getRandomInt(50,100)],
            randomScalingFactor(),
            randomScalingFactor()
        ]
    }, {
        label: 'Dataset 2',
        backgroundColor: color(window.chartColors.blue).alpha(0.5).rgbString(),
        borderColor: window.chartColors.blue,
        data: [
            [-10, 30],
            [-20,-70],
            [getRandomInt(-10,-50), getRandomInt(-50,-100)],
            [getRandomInt(-10,-50), getRandomInt(-50,-100)],
            [getRandomInt(-10,-50), getRandomInt(-50,-100)],
            [getRandomInt(-10,-50), getRandomInt(-50,-100)],
            randomScalingFactor(),
            randomScalingFactor()
        ]
    }]

};
console.log(horizontalBarChartData);
window.onload = function() {
    console.log('t');
    console.log(horizontalBarChartData);
    let ctx = document.getElementById("Chart").getContext('2d');
    window.myHorizontalBar = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'horizontalBar',
        data: horizontalBarChartData,
        options: {
            // Elements options apply to all of the options unless overridden in a dataset
            // In this case, we are setting the border of each horizontal bar to be 2px wide
            elements: {
                rectangle: {
                    borderWidth: 2,
                }
            },
            responsive: true,
            legend: {
                position: 'right',
            },
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Chart.js Horizontal Bar Chart'
            }
        }
    });
};

document.getElementById('randomizeData').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var zero = Math.random() < 0.2 ? true : false;
    horizontalBarChartData.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
        dataset.data = dataset.data.map(function() {
            return zero ? 0.0 : randomScalingFactor();
        });

    });
    window.myHorizontalBar.update();
});

var colorNames = Object.keys(window.chartColors);

document.getElementById('addDataset').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var colorName = colorNames[horizontalBarChartData.datasets.length % colorNames.length];
    var dsColor = window.chartColors[colorName];
    var newDataset = {
        label: 'Dataset ' + horizontalBarChartData.datasets.length,
        backgroundColor: color(dsColor).alpha(0.5).rgbString(),
        borderColor: dsColor,
        data: []
    };

    for (var index = 0; index < horizontalBarChartData.labels.length; ++index) {
        newDataset.data.push(randomScalingFactor());
    }

    horizontalBarChartData.datasets.push(newDataset);
    window.myHorizontalBar.update();
});

document.getElementById('addData').addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (horizontalBarChartData.datasets.length > 0) {
        var month = MONTHS[horizontalBarChartData.labels.length % MONTHS.length];
        horizontalBarChartData.labels.push(month);

        for (var index = 0; index < horizontalBarChartData.datasets.length; ++index) {
            horizontalBarChartData.datasets[index].data.push(randomScalingFactor());
        }

        window.myHorizontalBar.update();
    }
});

document.getElementById('removeDataset').addEventListener('click', function() {
    horizontalBarChartData.datasets.splice(0, 1);
    window.myHorizontalBar.update();
});

document.getElementById('removeData').addEventListener('click', function() {
    horizontalBarChartData.labels.splice(-1, 1); // remove the label first

    horizontalBarChartData.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
        dataset.data.pop();
    });

    window.myHorizontalBar.update();
});
```

I asked for a float bar. However, in fact, only a bar chart was displayed.
If you can not do it in Chart.js, I would appreciate it if you could show other possible libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Floating bars** are officially available since [**Chart.js v2.9.0**](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/releases/tag/v2.9.0). The feature was merged into [chartjs:master](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js) with [pull request #6056](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/6056). Individual bars can now be specified with the syntax `[min, max]`.

[image]

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Floating Bars</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    canvas {
      -moz-user-select: none;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <canvas id="canvas" height="100"></canvas>
  </div>
  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
      window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'horizontalBar',
        data: {
          labels: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
          datasets: [{
            label: 'data',
            data: [[-3, 5], [2, 10], [1, 3], [-4, -1], [4, 8]],
            backgroundColor: 'lightblue'
          }]
        },
        options: {
          responsive: true,
          legend: {
            position: 'top',
          },
          title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Horizontal Floating Bars'
          }
        }
      });
    };
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: is the 5th pair in the data array just a typo?

Comment: @gph: Indeed there was a mismatch between the number of entries in `labels` and `data`. I corrected the code, thanks for the hint.

Comment: Is it possible to have more than one floating bar per label?

Comment: @SebC: simply define several datasets together with the option `scales.yAxes.stacked: true` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60976218/2358409).