# Stacked Floating Horizontal Bar using ChartJS

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, bar-chart

I am trying to implement **Stacked Horizontal Floating Bars** using **ChartJS** but there is an unusual behaviour that I am facing. Can someone please help why is this happening. The code that I am using is :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Floating Bars</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        canvas {
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <canvas id="canvas" height="100"></canvas>
    </div>
    <script>         
      window.onload = function() {
         var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
         window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'horizontalBar',
            data:{
               labels:[1],
               datasets:[
               {
                 label:'data',
                 data:[[-3, 5]],
                 backgroundColor: 'lightblue'
               },
               {
                 label:'data',
                 data:[[6,8]],
                 backgroundColor: 'lightblue'
               },
               {
                 label:'data',
                 data:[[10, 11]],
                 backgroundColor: 'lightblue'
               }
               ]
            },
            options: {
               responsive: true,
               scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                  stacked : true,

                 }],
                 yAxes: [{
                  stacked : true,

                 }]
               },
               legend: {
                 position: 'top',
               },
               title: {
                 display: true,
                 text: 'Horizontal Floating Bars'
               }
            }
         });
      };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The output of the following code is : 
[image]

Now if we compare the code with the plotted data we see that the first and the second data set i.e. [-3,5] and [6,8] gets plotted correctly, but the third data set instead of getting plotted at [10,11] gets plotted at [16,17] i.e by adding 10 to the previous 6. Can someone please explain the cause for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that you're stacking the values on the `xAxis`.

Simply define xAxis as follows and you get the result you're expecting.

```
xAxes: [{
  stacked: false,
}]
```

```js
window.myBar = new Chart(document.getElementById('canvas'), {
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  data: {
    labels: [1],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'data 1',
        data: [[-3, 5], [6, 8], [10, 11]],
        backgroundColor: 'lightblue'
      },
      {
        label: 'data 2',
        data: [[6, 8]],
        backgroundColor: 'lightblue'
      },
      {
        label: 'data 3',
        data: [[10, 11]],
        backgroundColor: 'lightblue'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: false,
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
      }]
    },
    legend: {
      position: 'top',
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Horizontal Floating Bars'
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" height="80"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works perfectly as expected

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: This code is working for me too. Thanks. Is there a way to have one background color per label ?

Comment: @SebC: simply define different `backgroundColor` for each dataset.

Comment: @uminder Thanks, but I would like to have a color per row (per labels, ie: [1]). The backgroundColor works the other way, it set a color per label (ie: 'data 1'). Is it possible?